# Are these slow query log entries indicating a server overload or inefficient queries?

Tags: mysql, load, cpu-usage

Needing some insight. The slow query log is slowly expanding with errors like this. I'm new at the analysis of these, but it seems that these queries aren't necessarily slow.

Is it possible that the server is overloaded or backing up at these times? Any other ideas appreciated. (Looking at rows_examined, lock_time and query_time)

```
# Time: 130427 13:05:10
# User@Host: acctname_member[acctname_member] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 8.702061  Lock_time: 0.000059 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
UPDATE Notification SET nextFile = IF(nextFile = 999, 100, nextFile + 1);

# Time: 130427 13:05:21
# User@Host: acctname_member[acctname_member] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 6.796559  Lock_time: 0.000039 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
UPDATE check_it SET accomp = 'In Process', verbose = '258', delta = '0 -atl (1)' WHERE Num = '162615';

# Time: 130427 15:37:53
# User@Host: acctname_member[acctname_member] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 6.350998  Lock_time: 0.000033 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
UPDATE User SET mobileOS = 'iPhone 6.1.3', monthlyLogin = monthlyLogin + 1, lastVisit = NOW() WHERE empNum = 387;
```

Note: These queries are running hundreds of times per day, but only seldom making the slow list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many factors to recognize before jumping to conclusion that the queries are "slow".

- Queries will appear more often in the log when the server is heavily
  loaded than when it is not, so you should evaluate query execution
  time against general system activity.
- If your server is run with the `--log-queries-not-using-indexes`
  option, the slow query log also will contain queries that execute
  without using any indexes.
- Also, it doesn't hurt to use the `EXPLAIN` statement to see how the
  query optimizer processes these queries.

For the first one, you can periodically use the `SHOW PROCESSLIST` statement.

Comment: 'For the first one...' Do you mean your 1st bullet?

Comment: Yes, the `SHOW PROCESSLIST` statement will give you information about what queries are currently running.  Please see the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-processlist.html) for more informaiton and keep in mind, that you need to have the `PROCESS` privilege to see the full information.